# How was the answer achieved in this situation? (Counting)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> For any integer $n \geq 1$, let $B_n$ be the number of bitstrings of length $n$ that do not contain the substring $11$ and do not contain the substring
>   $101$. Which of the following is true for any $n \geq 4$?

$B_n = B_{n−1} + B_{n−3}$

I'm having trouble understanding how this is the answer, could someone explain why it's not $B_n = B_{n−2} + B_{n−3}$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It's not $B_n=B_{n-2}+B_{n-3}$ because $B_1=2,B_2=3,B_4=6,$ and $6=\ne3+2.$ Do you want us to explain what's wrong with your **reasoning** that led you to believe that $B_n=B_{n-2}+B_{n-3}?$ How can anyone do that, when you **haven't shown us your reasoning?**

Answer (score 2):

Assume $n \ge 4$.

If a legal string of length $n$ starts with a $1$, it must be followed by two $0$ bits, and then followed by any legal string of length $n-3$, so $B_{n-3}$ such strings.

If a legal string of length $n$ starts with a $0$, it must be followed by a legal string of length $n-1$, so $B_{n-1}$ such strings.

Thus, in total, for $n \ge 4$, you get $B_{n-1}+B_{n-3}$ legal strings of length $n$.